# DSV - SSAS Project - New 2 Columns In Table Change More then I Planned

Tags: sql-server, data-warehouse, ssas, visual-studio-2010

I encountered a very weird thing. 
I added in my DWH table 2 new columns but when I refreshed the DSV after adding this to my multidimensional project I saw that more (3) columns have been "changed". 
I did not touch these 3 columns(Marked in red ) they were already in my database before and have been handled .

Someone have an idea why this happened? Can I know what "changed"?
Also you can see each "changed column appears twice.

Here Is the PrintScreen After I refresh the DSV.
Marked In blue - the columns I added
Marked In red - the Columns I did not touch and was existing in the Table.

[image: Dsv]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have no idea why the columns changed appear twice and neither does google apparently.

With regards to the changes on the columns on the other hand your best option would be to compare the data types and table definitions on the .dsv.

Compare your new dsv to an old version of your dsv and have a look at all these [datasource view properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174812.aspx)

Certainly something has changed, maybe not necessarily in the datasource, but in what has been detected. It could be minor (correcter guessing of length for example) or a real problem, so I suggest you review the changes anytime this happens.

You could have a go at diffing the .dsv xml structure instead of reviewing each property. That sometimes looks messy but you could have some luck with [BIDSHelper](https://bidshelper.codeplex.com/)'s [SmartDiff's](https://bidshelper.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Smart%20Diff&referringTitle=Documentation) feature.